# Javascript to copy fields from dynamic forms

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm building a website that will allow a user to register many people at one time for something. The user selects the number of people they want to register, and then the next page populates that many forms.

I'm using PHP and CodeIgniter to do this.

For example, lets say there are 3 people being registered, and I am collecting the first name for each person.  What I do is loop this 3 times:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName[]" value="" maxlength="50" class="text small"  />
```

Notice the name of it.

Well, what I'm trying to do is implement a button that will allow the user to "Copy From Previous".  The trouble I'm running into is that I need the name of the previous and current form in order to do it.

On the back when when I save the data, I can access it through index.  Is there a way to do this with javascript?

Comment: Not sure how to accept answers :/

So, You know how when you check out at an online store, you can sometimes click a checkbox that copies your shipping info to your billing info?    I want to do something like that.  But if I have 3 first name fields, the way I have it, they're all named "firstName[]".

Does Javascript have a way to specify which field i'm talking about?

Comment: javascript isn't my strong point, so i'm just freestyling here. but couldn't you use getElementsByName and loop over the result to find the previous match and copy that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, give them all the same class and loop through the selected elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hwdxg/1/

```
$('input.fields').each(function(){
     $('body').append("<input value='"+$(this).val()+"'>");
});
```

Comment: related to your statement "give them all the same ID", you should ''never'' have elements with the same id on a page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery.

To get an array of input elements with `name="firstname[]"` you could do:

```
var firstname_array = $('input[name="firstname[]"]');
```

You will need to do that every time you add another input with `name="firstname[]"` to the page.

Then you could access each element through an index like so:

```
var index = 0;
alert($(firstname_array[index]).val());
```